# How does one properly write the end quotation marks for a quote, within a quote, within a quote --a triple quotation?ation

Tags: punctuation

How do I properly write the end quotation marks for a quote, within a quote, within a quote --A triple quotation?

Comment: Give us an example of your attempt. Also, what research have you done? Have you googled and found any pages showing you what to do? If so, why did the explanations not suffice for your question?

Comment: That obviously depends on what style of quotation marks you’re using for your quotes, quoted quotes, and quoted quoted quotes to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of clarity for your reader, along with what tools you have at hand. With only single quotes and double quotes, I would alternate between double and single:

> He recalled his father saying "She announced she was 'All done with "air quotes" ' and all those affectations."

Considering the modern attention span, and without disrespect for intellectuals, if you use more than one quote within another, you risk losing the reader—or at least forcing a reread. That is a matter of style.

Comment: The example of the tripple quotation that i want to use and need to know what quotatn marks to use, and where to use them,e are as follows:  __Moma appeared at Tony's door and said, "Tony, while we were watching you dance tonight, i heard the voice of Papaing, say, "Moma, I'm so proud of our son and his beautiful dancing tonight. While he was dancing, I heard the voice of the Lord, Almighty, echoing through the heavens saying, 'Dance, Mi pequeno!  --- Dance! --- Dance! ---Dance!""'""

Comment: Your example helps, and it needs fixing so we can see why there are so many quotes in a row at the end: At a minimum, pair the quotation marks so double, double, single quotes end in the reverse order: single, double, double. Remove clutter by moving the last quote away from the sentence end. Add a space between quotes-in-a-row. The sentence is overlong no matter the punctuation. Why not remove one of the quotes by referring to what someone said indirectly without quoting it?